# Javabean Introspector - what is in my List?

Tags: java, javabeans

I use this code to find out all Java List in a given class:

```
BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(classx);
PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = beanInfo .getPropertyDescriptors();

for (PropertyDescriptor pd : propertyDescriptors) {
    Class<?> ptype = pd.getPropertyType();

    if ((ptype+"").contains("java.util.List")) {
        System.out.println("list class property: " + pd.getName() + ", type=" + ptype); 
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
class property: value, type=interface java.util.List
```

The question is how to find out what type is in the List?
For this example this list is defined in classx as:

```
@JsonProperty("value")
private List<Value> value = new ArrayList<Value>();
```

How can I know the list is a list of Value objects?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get that via Property introspection, due to Type Erasure. Anything with type `Class` has no generic type parameter information (directly at least; super-type relationships do).
To get to generic type declarations you need to be able to access `java.lang.reflect.Type` (of which `Class` is one implementation; but ones with generic parameters are `GenericType`).

There are libraries that allow you to fully resolve generic types, for example [java-classmate](https://github.com/FasterXML/java-classmate). It will give you access to fully resolved type information for `Field`s and `Method`s, but from that point you will need to figure out logical Bean properties. It is probably possible to combine the two, if you want, so that you could use Bean Introspection for finding `Method`s, then match that with resolved information `java-classmate` can offer.

Comment: Thanks Stax. It is a little hard to believe that this cannot be done within JDK.

Comment: Yes, I wish JDK included proper type introspection starting with 1.5 when generics were introduced. But the root cause is that `java.lang.reflect.Type` is incredible badly designed from usage perspective: while it does expose necessary information, it is in very difficult to use form, scattered. Reconstructing information correctly is rather complicated business. It is also important to know what the usage is like, to know which aspects to expose and how: type information is needed for wide variety of usages.